# AWS Global Accelerator Static IP not working

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services

So I have just setup an application load balancer but I need a static IP to whitelist my database connection, I found Global Accelerator can do the job so I have set it up and assigned it to the ALB. All showing fine in the console but when I ping my domain ([www.example.com](http://www.example.com)), I don't see either of the 2 static IP's assigned... and when I whitelist both IP's my application still cannot connect.
Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. ALB is *only for inbound connections*. If you need to whitelist your web server's IP in your database ALB won't help you.
2. Global Accelerator IP is most likely an overkill for your case. **Assign Elastic IP to your web server** instance instead. That's what's going to be used for the outbound connections to the database.
3. If you are running the web servers in Autoscaling Group then keep your web server instances in a *Private subnet* and route out to the internet through a **NAT Gateway**. The NAT Gateway has fixed elastic IPs (one in each Availablity Zone) and all outbound traffic from the web servers will appear to come from these NAT GW IPs. Regardless how many web servers you have and how often they roll over in the ASG.

   Keeping your web servers in a private subnet without a direct inbound access is by the way the recommended setup anyway. All the access should be done through the ALB (web traffic) and since they are in ASG you shouldn't need to SSH to them anyway, they should be auto-configuring themselves upon launch. But if you still need to SSH to them use [**SSM Sessions**](https://aws.nz/projects/ssm-session/) - they don't need direct internet access.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Ok but I guess my only concern is that since im in a load balanced environment, what if the autoscaling removes the instance or adds another. Will I need to assign more elastic IPs? Are these reused when an instance is removed/created? Thanks again.

Comment: @Jat90 then the best option is to use a private subnet and a NAT Gateway - I have updated the answer.

Comment: thanks, I'll try and set up as you suggested now. cheers

Comment: Yes, so this is indeed the way to go. I'm in the process of setting this structure up, have some issues here and there but I will post different topics. Thanks again!